# How to measure network bandwidth over time?

Tags: networking, bandwidth

I have been struggling with my internet provider for a month now. Our bandwidth is too low for the price we are paying for our internet contract.

**Is there any method/tool/program to monitor my internet bandwidth (download speed) constantly for like a day or at least for 6-8 hours?**

I would like to **make an excel or pdf from the result log** so I can show them to proof that they service is too low.

The one-time measurements not good enough because sadly all the time when I contact their support our connection works well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you take that measurement? You will probably have to write a script that tests periodically. Your router might have a display as well (reported from the other side/negotiated) which you might be able to grab but which might be different from the real max. Why do you assume your bandwidth is not available all the time? What kind of connection to do you have?

Comment: I take the measurements via speedtest dot com. I assume my bandwidth is not available all the time because me and my flatmates experience really slow internet connection at the same time each day twice or even more. We have cable net and we use it via WiFi (but we are very close to it like 2-5 meters.)

Comment: This project exposes the speedtest 'api' to the command. Once installed you can trivially write a batch script to run the test every X minutes and log the results to a file. https://github.com/zpeters/speedtest/blob/master/README.md

Comment: A caveat - you can't make a valid assessment of your Internet service over a wifi link - there are countless variables at play with a wifi connection and unless you have the ability to nearly simultaneously test the.pc to local router throughput you can't isolate the cause of slowdowns. Run this test on a wired connection.

Comment: Is there anything you and your flat mates are doing around that time?

Comment: @Seth Yes we are using it for youtube, playing games, facebook, etc.